# How to run a function every 15 days?

Tags: flutter, datetime

I know that I can use `Future.delayed()` and `Timer` but because I'm working with days, I don't know if those are the most efficient ways of implementation.

Also, I think that closing the app would be a great factor in this, because it may reset the `Future.delayed()` and `Timer`.

So I used DateTime.now(), but it doesn't work because every time that the user lands on this page, the variables **dateTime** & **dateTimeHolder** are given `DateTime.now()` again .-.

This is what I have:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime dateTimeHolder = DateTime.now();

void resetUsers() {
  if (dateTime.isAfter(dateTimeHolder.add(Duration(days: 15)))) {
    //where the reset would happen
    dateTimeHolder = DateTime.now();
  }
}
```

Any ideas?
If more information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: Better don't do this in code. Use a [crontab](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm) which is exactly made for doing such tasks.

Comment: What platform are you deploying to? It makes a huge difference

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is saving `dateTimeHolder` in [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) as soon as it is set. This way the value can be saved over app restarts.

[Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value) is a great article from the Flutter Cookbook about persistence using key/value store.

You simply use this to read and write the `dateTimeHolder`:

```
final TRIGGER_DATE_KEY = "TRIGGER_DATE_KEY";

void storeTriggerDate(DateTime time) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  preferences.setString(TRIGGER_DATE_KEY, time.toIso8601String());
}

Future<DateTime> readTriggerDate() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String iso = preferences.getString(TRIGGER_DATE_KEY);
  return DateTime.parse(iso);
}
```